# KeystoneJS middleware running twice when making a call to MongoDB using Model.find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, keystonejs

I have a route that loads a list of Condos and displays them:

```
app.get( '/condo-list', middleware.loadCondoList, routes.views.condolist );
```

The loadCondoList middleware makes a call to the CondoBuilding model and sets the results on res.locals:

```
exports.loadCondoList = function loadCondoList( req, res, next ) {

console.log( 'request url: ' + req.url );
console.log( 'getting condo buildings...' );

CondoBuilding.model
    .find()
    .exec( ( err, condos ) => {
        if ( err ) {
            // pass error along
            next( err );
        } else {
            // add CondoBuildings to locals
            res.locals.condoBuildings = condos;
            next();
        }
    });
};
```

The call to the database is successful and the page renders as expected.  However, for some reason, the route is running twice.  The console output is as follows:

```
request url: /condo-list
getting condo buildings...
GET /condo-list 304 344.532 ms
request url: /condo-list
getting condo buildings...
GET /condo-list 304 317.631 ms
```

I have reproduced this behavior in multiple browsers ( Chrome, Safari, Firefox ) and verified that this does not happen on any other routes.

If I delete the call to `CondoBuilding.model.find()` and just call `next()` in the body of `loadCondoList()` this behavior does not occur.

I am running Keystone 4 `"keystone": "4.0.0-beta.5"` which leverages Express 4 `"express": "4.14.0"`

Below is the full list of routes I am running in the app, in case it is relevant:

```
// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function ( app ) {

// Views
app.get( '/', routes.views.index );
app.get( '/condo-list', middleware.loadCondoList, routes.views.condolist );
app.get( '/blog/:category?', routes.views.blog );
app.get( '/blog/post/:post', routes.views.post );
app.get( '/about', routes.views.about );
app.get( '/search', middleware.getAccountType, routes.views.search );

app.all( '/contact', routes.views.contact );

};
```

CondoList view:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
var locals = res.locals;

// locals.section is used to set the currently selected
// item in the header navigation.
locals.section = 'condolist';

// Render the view
view.render('condolist');
};
```

I have been debugging this issue for a while but I am at my wits end as to what could be causing this.  Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I followed @phuhgh's advice and ran the application in Express debug mode.  While nothing jumped out at me immediately, I did notice something strange during application startup.

Here is a sequence of a few routes being prepared that behave normally:

```
express:router:layer new / +0ms
express:router:route new /blog/post/:post +0ms
express:router:layer new /blog/post/:post +0ms
express:router:route get /blog/post/:post +0ms
express:router:layer new / +0ms
express:router:route new /about +0ms
express:router:layer new /about +0ms
express:router:route get /about +0ms
express:router:layer new / +0ms
express:router:route new /search +1ms
express:router:layer new /search +0ms
express:router:route get /search +0ms
```

Here is the sequence of the condo-list route being prepared:

```
express:router:layer new / +0ms
express:router:route new /condo-list +0ms
express:router:layer new /condo-list +0ms
express:router:route get /condo-list +0ms
express:router:layer new / +0ms
express:router:route get /condo-list +0ms
```

As you may notice, the `express:router:route get /condo-list +0ms` line is repeated.  I have no idea why, but I am assuming this has something to do with the issue I am running into.  I am digging into this angle a bit more, but again, any help from someone with a bit more knowledge in this area would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 2 - Stack Trace**

[image: Stack Trace]

I've debugged and gone through the stack step by step.  I can follow the path from function to function and everything appears normal, but my baseline for normal was looking at other routes that worked properly. I honestly wouldn't know what to look for once I'm that deep into the guts of Express.

Observations I have made while going through the stack:

- The stack trace is exactly the same both times the `/condo-list` route runs.
- The stack trace ( minus the loadCondoList middleware, of course ) is exactly the same for other routes that run properly ( i.e. only once ).
- If I add a call to loadCondoList in another route, it also runs properly.

  - e.g. I updated the `/about` route definition to the following: `app.get( '/about', middleware.loadCondoList, routes.views.about );` and it loads the data properly and only runs once.

Is there anything I should be paying particular attention to as I'm stepping through the Express lib code?  I feel a bit out of my depth there and I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: Can you post the code for routes.views.condolist?

Comment: CondoList View added - there's nothing going on as all of the loading is taken care of in middleware.

Comment: try enabling express debug mode as described here https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

Comment: thanks @phuhgh - I did not know about that mode, I will give it a shot!

Comment: Use **findOne** instead **find**, it makes sense and is good approach because you are interested in finding one-record only whereas there is no harm in using later one.

Comment: I'm actually retrieving all of the CondoBuildings and displaying them in a gallery, so find() is appropriate in this use case.  Is there any relevance to findOne() vs. find() in regards to the issue I'm trying to solve with the route running twice?

Comment: @n-devr are you using a debugger? If you set a breakpoint in the call-back looking at the stack will probably tell you what's going on. See https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js if you're unfamiliar.

Comment: @phuhgh yes I am using the VS Code debugger - I added details of what I gathered from stepping through the stack to the question.  Thanks for the continued advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of debugging I've finally found the culprit, and it was hiding in the most unlikely of places: the view!

**Context**

The view loads a masonry display of condo buildings that can be filtered by neighborhood.  Below is a relevant snippet of the masonry itself:

```
<!-- Condo List Masonry -->
<div class="condo-items">
{{#each condoBuildings}}
    <div class="condo-item {{neighborhood.key}}">
        <div class="condo-thumb">
            <span class="condo-tag tag-art">{{neighborhood.name}}</span>
            <a href="/{{condoUrl}}"><img src="{{{cloudinaryUrl image}}}" alt="{{name}}" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="condo-body">
            <h3><a class="condo-name" href="#">{{name}}</a></h3>
            <p>{{condoDescription}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

The issue was caused by the `cloudinaryUrl` helper in this line:

`<a href="/{{condoUrl}}"><img src="{{{cloudinaryUrl image}}}" alt="{{name}}" /></a>`

Here is the helper code:

```
_helpers.cloudinaryUrl = function (context, options) {

    // if we dont pass in a context and just kwargs
    // then `this` refers to our default scope block and kwargs
    // are stored in context.hash
    if (!options && context.hasOwnProperty('hash')) {
        // strategy is to place context kwargs into options
        options = context;
        // bind our default inherited scope into context
        context = this;
    }

    // safe guard to ensure context is never null
    context = context === null ? undefined : context;

    if ((context) && (context.public_id)) {
        options.hash.secure = keystone.get('cloudinary secure') || false;
        var imageName = context.public_id.concat('.', context.format);
        return cloudinary.url(imageName, options.hash);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

**The Issue**

Some CondoBuilding models did not have an `image` defined yet.  This causes the `context` argument in the `_helpers.cloudinaryUrl` method to be `undefined`.  In those cases, the helper will return `null`.  I am still unsure as to why this leads to a page reload, but I am certain that this was the culprit.

**The Fix**

Updating the Handlebars template to only render the `<img>` element if an image exists on the CondoBuilding model.  The updated template code looks as follows:

```
<!-- Condo List Masonry -->
<div class="condo-items">
{{#each condoBuildings}}
    <div class="condo-item {{neighborhood.key}}">
        <div class="condo-thumb">
            <span class="condo-tag tag-art">{{neighborhood.name}}</span>
            <a href="/{{condoUrl}}">{{#if image}}<img src="{{{cloudinaryUrl image}}}" alt="{{name}}" />{{/if}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="condo-body">
            <h3><a class="condo-name" href="#">{{name}}</a></h3>
            <p>{{condoDescription}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

With the addition of the `{{#if image}}` block to the template the route only runs once, as expected!

**Next Steps**

An improvement over this implementation would be to use a placeholder image for all CondoBuildings that do not have an `image` defined.  I will add this functionality shortly, but I couldn't resist updating with an answer as I've been banging my head against this issue for days now.

Thanks to everyone for your time and attention.

Comment: glad you found it. express:router:route get /condo-list was the problem as that calls next(), and the next thing is the same again (presumably followed by some keystone handler). The question is what the hell was registering it the second time? I'd guess keystone... You'd have to get down and dirty with express to know for sure though. Express' router is pretty simple, I’d be tempted to slap a breakpoint in it and find out.